# Getting a JSON array from a linq on c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to output data like this:

```
[[...],[...],[...],[...]]
```

But my query gives me this result:

```
[{...},{...},{...},{...}]
```

Here is my query:

```
  var result = (from c in displayedCompanies
                          group c by new { c.CodigoDeVenta } into s
                          select new{
                             ID = Convert.ToString(i++),
                             s.Key.CodigoDeVenta,
                             TotalInv = s.Sum(x => x.Inventario)
                             }).ToArray();
```

I've tried some options like the following but it's wrong:

```
  var result = (from c in displayedCompanies
                          group c by new { c.CodigoDeVenta } into s
                          select new [] {
                             ID = Convert.ToString(i++),
                             s.Key.CodigoDeVenta,
                             TotalInv = s.Sum(x => x.Inventario)
                             }).ToArray();
```

Note that the diference is the `[]` in `select new []`. I used to have a query before I implemented the "group by" that worked correctly, but after I added the group by this does not work anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: I would try `select new List<object>(){Convert.ToString(i++),s.Key.CodigoDeVenta,s.Sum(x => x.Inventario)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the grouping, focusing only on the syntax, your anonymous array (`new [] {...}`) should be fine.

However, it appears that you're trying to assign `Id =` and `TotalInv =` which looks like a leftover from the previous revision where you were selecting an anonymous object.

So, instead, you should be able to drop the member identifiers and select just the values you want in the child arrays:

```
select new [] {
    Convert.ToString(i++),
    s.Key.CodigoDeVenta,
    s.Sum(x => x.Inventario)
}
```